# ALSA sampling rate

Tags: audio, alsa

Couple of questions:

1. If you set the capture sampling rate in ALSA API to say 1000Hz, is the input really sampled at 1000Hz, or does the sound card always sample at its maximum capable sampling rate, removing unwanted samples and returning a PCM stream at the required sample rate?
2. Is there a variable bandwidth (with bandwidth determined by ALSA sample rate) anti-aliasing filter present on the sound card input, or should I put an anti-aliasing filter in the analog audio before providing it to sound card input?

Answer (score 2):

1. ALSA configures the sound card for the nearest supported sample rate.

   Which sample rates a sound card supports depends on the hardware.
2. Anti-aliasing filters depend on the hardware.

Comment: Is there a way to query HW whether anti-aliasing filter is present ?

Comment: Nothing but a datasheet, if you're lucky.

Answer (score 1):

If using `plughw` in the device name, ALSA will attempt to perform necessary conversions between the software making the request and the hardware. This includes anti-aliasing filters for resampling. If using `hw`, there may be an error or a format different from the one requested.

Example device names: `hw:0,0` and `plughw:0,0`. The system may have custom device names instead of `0,0`.

... I was unsuccessful finding an official text to quote to back this up. For such a commonly-used feature it is bafflingly underdocumented in the official user guides.